# Access Denied - While migrating classic to claims

Tags: migration, claims-based-auth, user-accounts

I was following the below links to migrate my classic site to claims based.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/20/migrating-from-windows-classic-auth-to-windows-claims-auth-in-sharepoint-2010-part-2.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx

While running the below command,

```
$WebAppName = "http://yourWebAppUrl"
#THIS SHOULD BE THE ACCOUNT THAT IS RUNNING THIS SCRIPT, WHO SHOULD ALSO BE A LOCAL ADMIN
$account = "yourDomain\yourUser"
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName
Set-SPwebApplication $wa -AuthenticationProvider (New-SPAuthenticationProvider) -Zone Default
```

## this will prompt about migration, CLICK YES and continue //

After clicking Yes, Getting **Access Denied**.

1. Management shell Running as Administrator
2. User login having local Admin Permission
3. User Login is SQL Dbo.

Comment: Make sure the user has the right permissions, you never know what people have done with the farm. Link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878.aspx#section3

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the Anders Aune comment and checked the permission and solved my problem.

// Make sure the user has the right permissions, you never know what people have done with the farm. Link: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878.aspx#section3 – Anders Aune //

Thanks to Colin & Rajesh...

Comment: This link is dead.  perhaps copying the relevant text would have been a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this instead:

```
$WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://url
$WebApp.UseClaimsAuthentication = "True" 
$WebApp.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://mysites.com"
$webApp.UseClaimsAuthentication = $True; 
$webApp.Update() 
$webApp.ProvisionGlobally()
$webApp.MigrateUsers($true)

Try and update the status which help others.